# Ambiguous prepositional phrase in a legal document

Tags: ambiguity

In common speech or writing, disambiguation of objects of prepositional phrases can be inferred from context. However, there is no room for error in filling out legal documents! I came across this question:

- *Have you enrolled or will soon enroll in health insurance but your health coverage has not started yet?*

The answer choices are: "Yes, I am enrolled", "I will soon enroll" and "No". I am currently enrolled in health insurance and it has already begun, but I have no idea how to answer this question (or whether I should skip it).

There is an ambiguity in the interpretation of this question. Logically, given propositions A, B, and C, the question " “A or B and C?” can be taken to mean either " A or (B and C) ? " or " ( A or B ) and C ? ", which are not equivalent questions.

Is there a correct interpretation?

Comment: I agree, wording is very poor. Is there someone you can contact for clarification? Without further clarification, I would be inclined to answer “no”, as the emphasis seems to be about health insurance that had not started yet.

Comment: I don't see any ambiguity. Of the three possible choices, *I am enrolled* is the only one that accurately describes your situation. In this case, it's the choices that count, not the phrasing of the question before them.

Comment: @Earlien, I asked a lawyer friend and they're as confused as I am!

Comment: @Jason Bassford, I understand your reasoning - "I am enrolled" certainly describes my situation. I'm concerned that that response suggests to the reviewer that "I am enrolled" *and* that my "health coverage has not started yet", which is not the case.

Comment: @ambiwords Actually, I meant trying to contact whomever sent the form or requires the filled-in form. They have a vested interest to help you fill it out correctly.

Comment: @Earlien Ah. This form comes from a government agency that is not accepting in-person consultation or phone calls, yet the submission due date is imminent! The situation is quite frustrating, so I appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: It's very poorly worded.

Comment: @ambiwords Write in your actual answer. Let them interpret that as they want. If you give your exact situation, there can be no confusion.

Comment: ... ie 'I am currently enrolled in health insurance and it has already begun.' If people of Jason's proficiency see this as being a question so poorly framed that one can make no assumptions about the way answers will be interpreted, the process needs improving.

Answer (score 1):

From a logical perspective, the problem with the question as posted —

> Have you enrolled or will soon enroll in health insurance but your health coverage has not started yet?

—is that it invites negative responses from people who fall into two fundamentally different categories.

On the one hand, if you have **not** enrolled in health insurance and will **not** soon enroll in health insurance, you can hardly answer "yes" to a question that states as its antecedent condition that you have enrolled or soon will enroll in health insurance; this is quite aside from the question of whether the coverage has started yet—although, obviously, it can't have started if you haven't enrolled.

But on the other hand, if you **have** enrolled and the coverage **has** begun, you can hardly answer "yes" to a question framed as "your health coverage has not started yet."

In short, the document asks this question in such a way that the only situation in which it would be logical to answer "yes" is one in which you **have** enrolled or will soon enroll in health insurance and yet the coverage **has not** yet begun.

If the author of the document for some reason cares only about people who fall into that particular category of respondents, it doesn't matter that two disparate groups of people get thrown into the same "no" category—and the question as worded has no fatal flaw.

But if the author of the document has any interest in distinguishing—now or in the future—between people who are already enrolled **and** covered and people who are **neither** enrolled **nor** about to enroll **nor** covered, that author is creating the conditions for a heap of trouble down the road that a more carefully worded question could easily have avoided.

---

With regard to the grouping issue related to whether the question should be read as

> (Have you enrolled or will soon enroll in health insurance) but your health coverage has not started yet?

or as

> Have you enrolled or (will soon enroll in health insurance but your health coverage has not started yet)?

I think the issue is illusory in this particular case—although it is certainly very important for people who are drawing up legal documents to be aware of the logical complications posed by sentences that might be interpreted either as "A or (B but C)" or as "(A or B) but C."

It is illusory in this case because the "but C" clause of the sentence is nontrivial only when applied to the "A" clause; the "B" clause necessarily implies the "but C" clause here. That is, it is possible for someone to have enrolled but not yet begun to be covered (assuming that coverage doesn't start at the moment of enrollment), but it is not possible to be planning to enroll "soon" and to be covered already.

Therefore, the combination "[you] have enrolled in health insurance but your health coverage has not started yet" presents a meaningful subcategory within the category "[you] have enrolled in health insurance"; but "[you] will soon enroll in health insurance but your health coverage has not started yet" is trivial because every member of the "[you] will soon enroll in health insurance" category will also fall into the "[you] will soon enroll in health insurance but your health coverage has not started yet" subcategory.

It follows that reading the sentence as incorporating the ordering principle of "(A or B) but C" provides a logical justification for including the "but C" term, whereas reading the sentence as incorporating the ordering principle "A or (B but C)" renders the "but C" term completely superfluous.

I seem to recall from my law school days that courts have a bias toward interpreting contractual terms in a way that treats them as meaningful rather than meaningless; I would have that bias if I were a judge. But regardless of how a court might rule on this question as a matter of law, the logical argument favoring "(A or B) but C" over "A or (B but C)" in this case is extremely strong.

Comment: "But, M'Lud, my client is a Professor of Logic, not Pragmatics."

Answer (score 0):

The question on the form is worded as "Have you enrolled or will soon enroll in health insurance but your health coverage has not started yet?"

This is worded clumsily, for sure. But I think the intention is: "(Have you enrolled or will soon enroll in health insurance) AND your health coverage has not started yet?"

The reason being that if the government department wanted to know if you had health insurance, and then as a follow up question, if your health insurance had started yet or not, this would (should!) have been two seperate questions. That fact that it is written as a single question suggests the emphasis is on whether it has (not) started.

Since the OP has health insurance and it HAS started, I would be inclined to answer "no".

(This is not legal advice and I appreciate you have already sought independent legal advice. But given the nature of the wording, if you answer this question as truthfully and correctly as you can, if it turns out that they actually meant something else, I think you have a safety net - the blame lays squarely with them).

Answer (score 0):

Terrible question, but I would go with "No" because you insurance has already started.

It would be helpful to know more about this document and/or the context to understand what is most relevant or important to the entity that is asking the question - whether you have enrolled in a plan, or whether you currently have coverage.

Comment: Hello, Jason. Answers on ELU (or any SE site) are intended to be authoritative. Opinions, even if correct, are not what are required (and in this case could be seen as offering dubious legal advice).